# URL routing vs multiple scripts

Tags: php, architecture, url-routing

I'm trying to understand the benefits of using a URL routing (URL dispatch) over just running code from different scripts. Besides prettier urls (which can be accomplished via htaccess using either model), why would I direct /archive/ to dispatcher.php?path=/archive/ instead of, say, simply rewriting /*/ to *.php?  Is either one better in terms of code reuse? Organization? Error handling?

Have you ever switched from one model to the other? Why did you do so? How much work did the switch entail?

For context, I am currently using the multiple script method. The environment is Apache + PHP. It is a medium size project (40+ top level php pages).

Comment: the only real benefit is SEO-friendly or (rarely) human-readable links. doing it via mod_rewrite rules is a big headache. Also, consider `auto_prepend_file` which will bring all other features of single entry point into your current model.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that's the *only* real benefit. What about top-level error handling?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: The problem with `auto_prepend_file` is that it isn't very granular. I can't choose not to include it on a page (as far as I know).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One major advantage of routing is that you can do so conditionally, making decisions on where addresses route based on user data, session values, time of day, or whatever.  Most of my projects are too simple to use this method, but if you get into a more complex system, I think the having control over routing in the code gives you some extra power and options.

Comment: I guess it would be easy to route, say, a login form to the current page with out having an ugly "redirect" url parameter. Interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, it's great for making pretty URL's. It's an absolute pain to manually update .htaccess all the time.

My personal favorite benefit of URL routing is that your application won't have to use pesky includes on every page, as you can do this in the routing page's php code. You can also write an [class autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) there and you'll never have to write the word 'include' again.

If you use relative paths rather than absolute paths, you can always do everything relative to the location of your routing file instead of having to keep track of which folder you're in, and fix all this when you decide to move a file from one folder to another.

It's very easy to define application-wide constants. For example I never hardcoded my website's name anywhere, instead opting to use `echo SITE_NAME;`, and then my designers decided to change the website name twice. Luckily this constant defined at the top level was accessible everywhere without having to make includes on every page.

Another benefit is that it's very easy to do error, exception, and 404 logging/handling when you have one top-level file for everything.

Comment: I prefer to use the `include(dirname(__FILE__.'/relative/path')` pattern, rather than trying to change my includes every time I move a file.